# Why is docker-compose throwing an error?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, osx-elcapitan, docker-machine

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "app_default" with the default driver
ERROR: b'failed to parse pool request for address space "LocalDefault" pool "" subpool "": could not find an available predefined network'
```

What is the meaning of this error, and how can I fix it?

Additional context:

```
$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 6c29830
docker-py version: 1.8.1
CPython version: 3.5.1
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016


$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Wed Apr 27 00:34:20 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: so where is the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Post the docker-compose file obviously please.

Comment: @BMW  The problem was due to a docker-machine configuration error.  I'll answer my own question ASAP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using some vpn service? 
Here is a link to a possible reason:
https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/779

Comment: Indeed I am.  I didn't expect this to interact with docker, so sorry for omittng this element from my question!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem. Solved by removing all docker defined networks with:

```
docker network rm `docker network ls -q`
```

Comment: This resolved the issue for me as well. I did not feel comfortable removing all networks so used this command instead: docker network ls | grep '_default' | awk '{ print $1}' | xargs docker network rm